# How to build openmpi rpm from srpm cuda aware

Tags: linux, rpm, rhel, openmpi

I would like to build the OpenMPI 1.10.2 rpm from the srpm.
But I need to build it cuda aware.

According to the documentation (https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=buildcuda) I need to add `./configure --with-cuda`

Is there any way to do that while creating the rpm?
I tried:

- `rpmbuild -bb --with cuda openmpi-1.10.2.spec`
- `rpmbuild -ba openmpi-1.10.2.spec --define '--with-cuda'`

But no success.

Answer (score 0):

Use the second one, but edit the spec file. Find the call to `./configure` or the `%configure` macro being called, and add your `--with-cuda` to that line.

`rpmbuild -ba openmpi-1.10.2.spec`